# PHP ob_start() callback preg_match_all returns only the value 1 in the matches

Tags: php

I run a `php` site, and I'd like to try to combine all the CSS files into a single file using PHP. The way I try to achieve that is by utilizing the `ob_start()` function at the beginning of the application, and then using a callback function, in order to remove the `<link ...>` tags and get the CSS URLs in order to process and combine into a single file.

The problem I am faced with is that the `preg_replace()` works as expected, for remove the styles from the HTML, but the `preg_match_all()` in the `matches` variable contains the number `1`.

My code is like this:

```
// Start of my application
ob_start( 'process_css' );

function process_css( $buffer ) {
    // Try to match all the div tags in the document
    preg_match_all( '~div~', $buffer, $css_matches );

    // Create a new write file stream
    $f = fopen( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/matches.txt', 'w' );
    // Write the contents in the file
    fwrite( $f, print_r( $css_matches ), strlen( print_r( $css_matches ) ) );
    // Close the stream
    fclose( $f );

    // Remove the <link...> tags
    $buffer = preg_replace( '~\<link.*href\=[\'"].*\.css[^"\']*[\'"][^>]*\>~', '', $buffer );

    // Return the modified buffer.
    return $buffer;
}
```

And after running this code, my HTML has not the `link` tags, and the new generated `matches.txt` file has the following content:

```
1
```

*Note, that my HTML of course and contains lots of div elements.*

Am I doing anything wrong? Can you please suggest a solution? Unfortunately, I cannot see any obvious issue.

**UPDATE 1**

I just found that the `var_dump` returns nothing for the `$css_matches` variable while the `print_r` returns `1`

**UPDATE 2**

I just changed my code with the help of @KiJéy with the following:

```
$f = fopen( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/m.txt', 'w' );
fwrite( $f, var_export($matches, true), strlen( var_export($matches, true) ) );
fclose( $f );
```

But yet, using this code, the $matches array is empty. The output of the `preg_match_all` is the following:

```
array (
    0 => 
        array (
        ),
    )
```

**UPDATE 3**

By changing the code at the start of my script to this:

```
ob_start();
```

and put the following code in the footer:

```
$buffer = ob_get_clean();
preg_match_all( '/div/', $buffer, $matches );

echo "<pre>";
echo var_export($matches, true);
echo "</pre>";
```

I get the following output:

```
array (
    0 => 
        array (
            0 => 'div',
            1 => 'div',
            2 => 'div',
            3 => 'div',
            ...
        )
    )
```

Comment: `strlen(print_r($array))` doesn't make any sense. If you want the length of the string that sould be printed with `print_r` try `strlen(print_r($array, true))` but then again, I don't understand why you would do that

Comment: @KiJéy the actual problem is not the `print_r` and the `strlen`. Say I am wrong with it. The main problem is that `preg_match_all` returns an empty value for the `matches` array. Do you have any idea for what I can do with that issue?

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski do you have any suggestion about this problem? I see you are an experienced developer. Have you ever meet that problem again?

Comment: How do you know that ? All you have in your debug file `matches.txt` is the return value of `print_r` which is completely irrelevant. So try the same code again with `print_r($css_matches, true)` or with `var_export($css_matches, true)` if you want to know what's in your `$css_matches` variable. For now all you know is that `print_r()` returns 1 when the second argument is not set or set to `false`

Comment: @KiJéy OK, yes, you are right. I just did what you explain and I am going to update my question.